# Read SQL from sqlite3 database in Windows using connectorx

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to establish a connection to my sqlite3 database which is located on my laptop's hard drive. I used the follwing example code from https://sfu-db.github.io/connector-x/databases/sqlite.html:

```
import connectorx as cx
db_path = '/home/user/path/test.db'                         # path to your SQLite database
conn = 'sqlite://' + db_path                                # connection token
query = 'SELECT * FROM `database.dataset.table`'            # query string
cx.read_sql(conn, query)                                    # read data from SQLite
```

Since I'm using Windows the path to the database contains a colon:

```
db_path = 'E:/my_db.db'
conn = 'sqlite://E:/my_db.db'
```

When I try to execute `cx.read_sql(conn, 'select * from tablename')`  I get the following error message:
*[2023-01-21T19:01:47Z ERROR r2d2] unable to open database file: E/my_db.db*

What's interesing about the error message is that the path to the database which it displays is missing the colon. It is **E/my_db.db** instead of **E:/my_db.db**. It looks like a bug. So the question is: How to establish the connection to my database on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I got the hint to use `db_path = urllib.parse.quote(os.path.abspath(database_name))`  but it didn't really help me out. Now I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Conversion error from type Text at index: 11, trailing input
```

Comment: This seems to be an error with you data and not with the connection. So it seems that `db_path = urllib.parse.quote(os.path.abspath(database_name))` is a solution with the connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [the connector-x introduction about SQLite](https://sfu-db.github.io/connector-x/databases/sqlite.html):

```
import connectorx as cx
import urllib
db_path = urllib.parse.quote("C:\\user\\path\\test.db")     # url encode the path to your SQLite database         
conn = 'sqlite://' + db_path                                # connection token
query = 'SELECT * FROM `database.dataset.table`'            # query string
cx.read_sql(conn, query)
```

As you see, you should use doulbe back slashes on windows, something I guess happened when you used `db_path = urllib.parse.quote(os.path.abspath(database_name))` per your comment. While you still got an error, that was relating to your data - but you got a connection.